# Unity3d: Execute arbitrary javascript from C# object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, expression, unityscript, expression-evaluation

I would like to

```
string expression = "2+2";

public string evaluateExpresion(expression)
{
   return executeJavascript(expression); // Magic javascript executor
}

Debug.Log(evaluateExpression(expression);
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a javascript file with your desired functions and you can call them in your c# files if I don't misunderstand what you mean. In your example you can create:

```
// JavaScriptExpressions.js

function executeExpression( x : string ) {
    // Some code here..
}
```

JavaScript file and you can access the function by dragging js to the same transform with your c# file or you can drag it to a different transform. Or you can set it static if it is not connected to mono library. Here is the sample code for c#:

```
// YourCsharp.cs
string expression = "2+2";

public string evaluateExpresion(string expression) { 
    return transform.GetComponent<JavaScriptExpressions>().executeExpression(expression);
}

Debug.Log(evaluateExpression(expression));
```